# It's a security issue if I post the backend code of my open source project?

Tags: api, rest, backend

Currently I'm creating an open source project and I want people to participate in creating the backend code, a simple API. May sound newbie, but ive been told that I should never make public my backend code, for security reasons. Then how can people collaborate making the API if they can't make it public. They should secretly send me the code or there's no security issues by doing so.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a security issue itself. There are lots of good well-secure open source backends and libs to write backends are published in open public repositories.

And the opposite, if you deploy non-secure backend (i.e. with bugs, old exploited libs, etc.), even the privacy of your source code will not help you. Public source code will make it faster to break into, but it does not make it less secure comparing with the private code.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew, now I can keep forward with my open source project.